# Increment date, calculate date

Tags: php, date, increment

I have one particular problem, I have script which should issue bill statement. Now what I  want is that the due date of the bill must be 14 days after the issued date.

```
$issue_date = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_post['issued_date']));
$due_date  = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['due_date']));
$query = "insert into utility (issue_date, due_date)values(now(),now()+ (60 * 60 * 24 *14)";
```

But that is not really working at all. Any help please?

Comment: please stop re-introducing spelling mistakes to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`DATE_ADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function:

```
$query = "insert into utility (issue_date, due_date) values (now(),
    DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 14 DAY))";
```

Answer (score 1):

The key point is not to mix datetimes and unix timestamps.

If you have date/datetime columns in the database (as appropriate for `NOW()`) then you can't just add seconds, you want `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)`.

If you're using unix timestamps then you could do the addition with `strtotime('+14 days', $_POST['issued_date'])` in PHP or `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(...))` in MySQL.

Comment: Yes I have two Date columns in my DATABASE(issue_date column and Due_date columns.) the value for the issue_date is (Now(),) and I want the value of the DUe_date to be 14 days later!!, I actually tried to have automated this with having entry in the form.but some how it is not working!!

Comment: @sareeye sounds like setting due_date to `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)` in your query would work fine then.

Answer (score 0):

what is meant by 'due date of the bill must be 14 '?

Also you are evaluating now() twice - hence getting two values.

Comment: @jared, I was trying to formatt it correctly, I did not notice the someone formatted it already..

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with your code.

1. Variables in PHP are case-sensitive.  Meaning **$_post** is not the same as **$_POST**.
2. When you are multiplying the time by seconds, minutes, hours, and etc, it is not getting calculated
   because the multiplication is being interpreted as part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `now()+ (60 * 60 * 24 *14)` use `adddate(now(), interval 14 day)`. And you are missing closing `)` in your query!